# Redirect to ADFS login

Tags: domain-name-system, adfs, microsoft-office-365

My company has switched to Office 365 and we like it, but we would really like for the ADFS single sign on to be more simplified.  We have to go to login.microsoftonline.com then type in the username, then you have to click the link that appears at the bottom.  Then you have to type in your username again and password.  So we have come up with the idea that we could just redirect everyone to this page, but after lots of research into this, it seems like it's not possible to do a DNS redirect to a path.  Does anyone know any other type of redirect that we could try?  I'm thinking about trying to see if I can have a DNS entry go to our TMG and then have the TMG redirect to a path.  But I'm not sure how the ADFS server knows where to go after that, so it might just log us in and not go anywhere.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options here.

If you are using O365 for email, then advise users to goto https://outlook.com/owa/contoso.com assuming contoso.com is the federated domain. This will take them straight to ADFS, where they logon and then sent straight back to OWA.

If you are talking of logon to the portal itself or sharepoint, you should look at hosting smartlink on a server. Please see http://community.office365.com/en-us/w/sso/using-smart-links-or-idp-initiated-authentication-with-office-365.aspx

So you could have links made like

- www.contoso.com/portal = O365 portal
- www.contoso.com/sharepoint = Sharepoint team site

please note these are just examples but hopefully you'd see what i mean.